# how to use the result of mapWithState in spark streaming up in the driver code in next batch

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I am maintaining user profile state using mapWithState and i want to use the result of mapWithState up in driver code in next stream batch.

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  I am building a realtime user profiling system using spark streaming and  i am maintaining user profile state for 30 min using mapWithState and dump the user profile state to hbase. if a user record comes after that 30 min timeout i am fetching that user's stored user profile state from hbase , but making hbase connection in mapWithState will create a new hbase connection for every new entry . Therefore i decided to prefetch user profile state from hbase before mWState such that i can use it in mWState .  contd..

Comment: Therefore i need mapWithState's o/p to check whether there is need to fetch user profile state from hbase on per partition basis and then fetch required user state from hbase and then i use those results in mapWithState